# How to kill child_process in node.js?

Tags: node.js, kill

I'm starting `autossh` like

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var ssh = exec('autossh [...]', function() {});
```

Then when I do `ps aux | grep auto` I see that there are 2 processes:
`/bin/sh -c autossh -M22002 ...` and `/usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M22002`. The pid attribute I can read in node points to the `/bin/sh` process.

Now when I invoke `.kill` on the handler, the `/bin/sh` process is killed, but the `autossh` one does not. How do I kill both of them?